# .htaccess Display a directory on specific HTTP_HOST

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm currently trying to display a directory when a user reaches my server from a specific host.

Example:

http://websiteone.com/
would show
http://websitetwo.com/sub/websiteone/

as well as

http://websiteone.com/somepage.html
would show
http://websitetwo.com/sub/websiteone/somepage.html

The reason I'm trying to achieve this with .htaccess is because http://websiteone.com/'s DNS  points to http://websitetwo.com/

so right now, http://websiteone.com/apage.html will just show http://websitetwo.com/apage.html, rather than http://websitetwo.com/sub/websiteone/apage.html

I've achieved something similar with sub domains using the following htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub/ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=website.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.website.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.website\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) /sub/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

How can I do the same as above but with a different HTTP_HOST instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?websiteone\.com$
RewriteRule . http://websitetwo.com/sub/websiteone%{REQUEST_URI} [R]
```